# dispatch_async and autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, autorelease

I am using dispatch_async that in turns call other code that uses dispatch_async, which uses for-loop to allocate at least 50 - 100 objects.  How do I know when I should use @autoreleasepool? Can I just use @autoreleasepool in any dispatch_async that allocates more than 10 objects or is there a risk in using too many autoreleasepool?

Answer (score 7):

As the [Using Autorelease Pools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) section of the *Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide* advises to use autorelease pools where "either you must or it is beneficial to do so." I wouldn't generally advise just throwing in autorelease pools for no reason, though you can often do so without incident.

The `@autoreleasepool` is not needed unless you're dealing with your own `NSThread` instances (which you are not doing here), or if you are trying to explicitly reduce the high water mark caused by using many autorelease objects.

In terms of determining when you need autorelease pools to reduce peak memory utilization, it's not as simple as "I have ten objects." It's a question of the size of the objects and now many you have. If dealing with large images (e.g. 20000 x 20000 px), then more than one image may be too many. If dealing with small objects (strings, numbers, etc), then you can have thousands of objects without causing problems. And it only applies where you are using autorelease objects.

So, I'd suggest an empirical approach where you consider (a) at the peak amount of memory your routine uses; and (b) how many autorelease objects you're using, and make a decision from there.

It's worth noting, though, that there are some isolated situations where one must be careful adding an autorelease pool. The typical example is where you have a `NSError **` parameter to a method for which you pass back an object if there was some error. For example, this code is problematic:

```
/** Some method that will optionally return error object.
 *
 *  @param  error  The error object being returned
 *
 *  @return        This returns an NSData if successful, and `nil` upon error.
 *                 See NSError object to determine why it failed.
 */

- (NSData *)someMethod:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // do some stuff

        // following line is wrong as the error will be released when pool is drained 

        if (failure)
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kMyAppDomain code:code userInfo:nil];

        // etc
    }
}
```

In that case, you might refactor it like so:

```
- (NSData *)someMethod:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSError *localError;

    @autoreleasepool {

        // do some stuff

        // save it in some local variable outside of the scope of this block

        if (failure) {
            localError = [NSError errorWithDomain:kMyAppDomain code:code userInfo:nil];
        }
    }

    // now you can return it safely
    *error = localError;

    // etc
}
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, is there anything inherently wrong with using unnecessary autoreleasepools? If inserted in multiple places do they have any performance drags?

Comment: Generally it's not a problem, though it is an issue if you're returning autorelease objects (the typical example is where you have a `NSError **` parameter to a method). I only hesitate because I see far too many answers here in Stack Overflow that blithely answer any memory issue with "oh, throw in an `@autoreleasepool`" without any understanding of why and where you'd do that.

Comment: And what about dispatch_async? It is need to use @autoreleasepool in it?

Comment: @poGUIst - If you use dispatch queues or operation queues, no autorelease pool is needed. You only created autorelease pools if (a) you manually detach a `NSThread` or call `performSelectorInBackground`; or (b) you have code that loops, consuming an extraordinary amount of memory with autoreleased objects, and you want to drain your pool more frequently in order to minimize the maximum memory use (i.e. you don't want to wait until you yield back to the run loop or the dispatched block of code finishes).

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning almost half a decade later that even when using `NSError **`, autoreleasepools are no issue anymore as long as you use ARC. ARC will make sure you don't mess up that part which was a bit tricky in the past when you wanted to pass autorelease objects across the limits of an autoreleasepool.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being less than completely helpful...

You should add `@autoreleasepool`s when the Allocations template of Instruments shows you that your memory use during a particular workflow is significantly pushing up your application's high water mark (with autoreleased objects).

In other words, avoid premature optimization.